# Jquery help with pager and display elements.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists, pager

I have a `ul` `li` structure like this:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" class="next"></a>
    <a href="#" class="prev"></a>
    <ul>
        <li class="element element1"></li>
        <li class="element element2"></li>
        <li class="element element3"></li>
        <li class="element element1"></li>
        <li class="element element2"></li>
        <li class="element element3"></li>
        <li class="element element1"></li>
        <li class="element element2"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Initially I want only the first two `li`'s to be visible when the page loads. When the `.next` anchor tag is clicked the first two `li`'s should be hidden and the next two should be visible. Similarly `.previous` should do the opposite.

Comment: have you done any kind of javascript already for this case?

Answer (score 0):

very quick and dirty concept

http://jsfiddle.net/ULnd5/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

    var cur_el = 1;  

    $('.next, .prev').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        show_lis($(this).attr('class'));
    });

    function show_lis(dir){

        cur_el = (dir == 'next') ? cur_el + 2 : cur_el - 2;

        if(cur_el >= $('#my_list li').length+1)
        {
            cur_el = 1;
        }
        if(cur_el <= 0)
        {
            cur_el = $('#my_list li').length-1;
        }

        $('#my_list li').hide().siblings(':nth-child('+cur_el+')').show().next().show();
    }
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/kkdrs/

Comment: I'm getting this error -> Error: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child

Comment: `:nth-child()` was added in 1.1.4. Are you using a dinosaur version of JQuery? You likely have an error elsewhere in your code. Test it out on my jsfiddle link and you'll see there are no errors.